# How do you dismiss an AlertDialog and run some code?

Tags: flutter, dart, popup

**The problem**

So I have an AlertDialog in my flutter app, and it has two buttons: `yes` and `no`.
No matter which button is clicked, I want the pop up to be dismissed, however I also want to run some code if `yes` is pressed.

**My code**

```
showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                            title: Text("Delete?"),
                            content: Text("Do you want to delete this task?"),
                            actions: [
                              MaterialButton(child: Text("Yes"),onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
                              MaterialButton(child: Text("No"), onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
                            ],
                          ), barrierDismissible: true);
```

I would appreciate anyone's help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
actions: [
     MaterialButton(child: Text("Yes"),onPressed: () {
        //do something
        Navigator.pop(context))
     }),
     MaterialButton(child: Text("No"), onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
],
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I've solved the same issue. I'm not sure if there is a cleaner way of doing it

```
bool yesPressed = false;

showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Delete?"),
              content: Text("Do you want to delete this task?"),
              actions: [
                MaterialButton(
                    child: Text("Yes"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      yesPressed = true;
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    }),
                MaterialButton(
                    child: Text("No"),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
              ],
            ),
        barrierDismissible: true)
    .then((value) {
  if (yesPressed) {
    // Do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a value when you call your `Navigator.pop` which will be returned through the `Future` from `showDialog`. Here is a code sample:

```dart
showDialog<bool>(
   context: context,
   builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Delete?"),
      content: Text("Do you want to delete this task?"),
      actions: [
         MaterialButton(child: Text("Yes"),onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true)),
         MaterialButton(child: Text("No"), onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false)),
      ],
   ),
   barrierDismissible: true,
).then((bool hasTappedOnYes) {
   if (hasTappedOnYes) {}
   else {}
});
```